# Spark Multiclass Classification using python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, multiclass-classification

I am trying to implement Multiclass classification using pySpark, I have spent loads of time searching the web, and I have read that it is possible now using Spark 2.1.0.

I have generated my own dataset with all-numerical features and I have created a DataFrame as shown below;
[image: Features and the Classes('Service_Level')]

I have three classes 'Service_Level' which are either 0, 1 or 2.

Questions:

1. Do I have to use LabeledPoints if I have features like these?
2. how do I use a multilayer perceptron instead of logistic regression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no answer, I will share what I observed during research. using Labeled Points is ok when using the `Spark MLlib` which is now in maintenance mode in Spark 2.1.0. However, my features were categorical hence using the DataFrame API with `Spark ML`, I had to convert them to vectors using StringIndexer, OneHotEncoder and Pipelines to select my features and labels.

**Answering the question**
Yes, Labeled Points can be used with those features but when using Spark MLlib. I was not able to implement the Multilayer Perceptron because somehow it required `libsvm` formatted data which I did not have and could not convert my CSV into such.

In the final implementation, I had to use the Dataframe based API `Spark ml`